# angular2 rc.6 breaks systemjs / jspm module importing

Tags: angular, jspm

so with ng2 rc.6 I am getting an error of:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    Evaluating http://localhost:9089/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.6/src/browser/browser_adapter.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9089/src/App.ts`

I tried to map to umd as per chanegs with no luck:

`"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.6/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js",`

and help or sample is appreciated,

Sean.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the AOT, then I wouldn't make any changes. I thought that I'd have to update my config and mapped all the Angular packages to the umd bundle like you're showing but ended up changing it back. I also kept my tsconfig the same, too:

```
"target": "ES5",
"module": "system",
"moduleResolution": "node"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

issue was that I was accessing a private module as now you no longer can do that in RC.6
fixed it and all good tx!